# php find greater of two numbers

Tags: php

I am a straight novice in PHP. So, please do not down vote my question as it may seem very silly. I have a code to check if a number is greater than another number in php.

```
if($num1 > $num2)
{
    echo $num1
}
else
{
    echo $num2
}
```

The above code is the exact one in my file. But no output is being shown. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned on? If there is an error you won't know about it unless you have it enabled.

Comment: put semicolon after echo statements , make sure num1 and num2 has got values not null, cheers :)

Comment: remove 1 error_reporting(0)l; if you have as ur first statment in your php file and turn on error reporting.

Comment: @Cube32 no it wouldn't. Provided the code is fixed re semi-colons. One or other of the clauses would always fire. Its an if/else block.

Comment: duh, you're right @barryhunter - i have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John, the answer is very simple. You have not added a `;` at the end of your statement. Change your code to the following :-

```
if($num1 > $num2)
{
    echo $num1;
}
else
{
    echo $num2;
}
```

This code will surely work.

Answer (score 36):

The easiest way to do that is:

```
echo max($num1, $num2);
```

Comment: this should be the default answer

Comment: Thank you, but I guess OP won't see your comment, he hasn't been around for four years. Keep upvoting and it will eventually be displayed before the chosen answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code not included (equal case):

```
if($num1 > $num2)
{
    echo $num1;
}
elseif($num1 < $num2)
{
    echo $num2;
}else{
 echo "equal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add semicolon after each line:

```
if($num1 > $num2)
{
    echo $num1;
}
else
{
    echo $num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon has to be added after each line.
if($num1 > $num2) echo $num1;
else echo $num2;

Also additionaly there is no need to add brackets if there is only a single line written after if/else statements.

Comment: There's no *need*, but you *should*.

Comment: Yeah...I agree with @Juhana, as it gets confusing if you have very long php codes.